# Is there a class E corridor in the class B north of San Diego International?

Tags: air-traffic-control, general-aviation, navigation, flight-planning

I am a relatively new pilot in the Los Angeles area and I have a question related to the Class B Airspace north of San Diego International, adjacent to Torrey Pines Glider Port.  The LA Terminal Map and Fore Flight show what appears to be a corridor or brake in the Class B Airspace. It shows the B Airspace to be 18 to 100, however there appears to be an altitude box just to the left of this area with an arrow pointing to the area in question that says floor of 18 to ceiling of 32 & floor of 68 to ceiling of 100.

My interpretation of this is that this box designates a Class E corridor just above 3,200' and just below 6,800'.

I have asked a number of pilots more experienced than myself and have received conflicting answers to my interpretation. Some agree and some do not.  I have attempted to find references online, but the only reference to a corridor in San Diego is the VFR corridor that overflies San Diego International above 3,300 and below 4,700 Northwest to Southeast.

I have attached a photo of the chart from Fore Flight for the area in question.  I would appreciate if someone who has flown this area could clarify this for me I would be very grateful as I don't want to bust B Airspace. Is my interpretation of the chart correct?  If not can someone explain to me what the box is saying?   Thank You.  [image: San Diego Class B]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a frequent VFR owner/flyer in that area for past 12 years. The box is clearly identifying the floor within in the box it is pointing into.  That 1800/3200' is to keep transitioning aircraft either below or above the MIRAMAR MCAS departure corridor.  Aircraft that are inbound to Montgomery Field will often transition with a Class B clearance when flight followed by SoCal on 119.6, at 2500-3000'  Inbound commercial jets for Lindbergh Field will come thru that zone at 6800' and above. And yes, as depicted on the chart, offshore of Torrey Pines and west of the OCN 152 radial, the floor is 1800'.  If you're looking for a "corridor"to the South Bay onto Brown Field, you could fly the shoreline at 3600'-4600', from Del Mar, over Mt Soledad, and then join the VFR corridor over Lindbergh Field, and onto Brown Field.